# How to get values of a row to be placed in a modal (Codeigniter)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am using the codeigniter framework with the  element as my edit button. However, when I am trying to get the array values of the row in which the button was placed and selected it doesn't show. I also want to update or edit the said row. I don't know what's wrong with my code.

## Controller function

```
function fetch(){
    $data = array(

        'fo_supp' => $this->system_model->fetch('fo_supp', array('id' => $this->input->post('id')))
    );

    var_dump(data);




}
```

## Ajax function and view with modal

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    //-- Modal has finished being hidden
    $('#sfm_modal_edit').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
        //$(this).find('form')[0].reset();
    });



  

$(document).ready(function() { 
    
$('.editBtn').on("click", function() {
alert("test");
var rowID = $(this).attr('id');

$.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>SFM/fetch',
   method:"POST",
   data:  {
   'id': rowID
     },

success: function(data) {
console.log(data);
    $('#supp_codev1').value(data.SUPP_CODE);
    $('#address1v1').value(data.address1);
    $('#address2v1').value(data.address2);
    $('#countryv1').value(data.country);
    $('#descriptionv1').value(data.description);
    $('#tel_numv1').value(data.tel_num);
    $('#fax_numv1').value(data.fax_num);
    $('#contact_personv1').value(data.contact_person);
    $('#emailv1').value(data.email);
    $('#consol_agentv1').value(data.consol_agent);
    $('#disc1v1').value(data.disc1);
    $('#disc2v1').value(data.disc2);
    $('#disc3v1').value(data.disc3);
    $('#disc4v1').value(data.disc4);
    $('#disc5v1').value(data.disc5);
    $('#last_transactionv1').value(data.last_transaction);
    $('#old_supplierv1').value(data.old_supplier);

  $("#sfm_modal_edit").modal('show');

 }
});

});
});
</script>
```

```html
<!-- page content -->
<div class="right_col" role="main">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

    <div class="x_panel">
      <div class="x_title">
        <h2>Supplier Master File

          <small></small>
        </h2>
        <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
          <li>
            <a class="collapse-link">
              <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
              <i class="fa fa-wrench"></i>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li>
                <a href="#">Settings 1
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Settings 2
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="x_content">
        <div style="overflow: hidden;">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#sfm_modal" style="float: right;">
     <i class="material-icons">&#xE147;</i>
     <span>Add New Data</span>
    
   </button>
        </div>
        <table id="datatable-buttons" name="sfm_table" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Supplier Code
              </th>
              <th>Address
              </th>
              <th>Country
              </th>
              <th>Description
              </th>
              <th>Telephone Number
              </th>
              <th>Fax Number
              </th>
              <th>Contact Person
              </th>
              <th>Email
              </th>

              <th>Actions
              </th>
              <th>Consolidating Agent
              </th>
              <th>Discount 1
              </th>
              <th>Discount 2
              </th>
              <th>Discount 3
              </th>
              <th>Discount 4
              </th>
              <th>Discount 5
              </th>
              <th>Last Transaction
              </th>
              <th>Old Supplier
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <?php if(!empty($fo_supp)): ?>
            <?php foreach($fo_supp as $supp): ?>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <?=$supp->SUPP_CODE?>
              </td>
              <td>
                <?=$supp->ADDRESS." ".$supp->ADDRESS2?>
              </td>
              <td>
                <?=$supp->COUNTRY?>
              </td>
              <td>
                <?=$supp->DESCRIPTION?>
              </td>
              <td>
                <?=$supp->TEL_NO?>
              </td>
              <td>
                <?=$supp->FAX_NO?>
              </td>
              <td>
                <?=$supp->CONTACT?>
              </td>
              <td>
                <?=$supp->EMAIL?>
              </td>
              <td>

                <a href="#sfm_modal_edit" id='<?=$supp->SUPP_CODE?>' class="editBtn" data-toggle="modal">
                  <i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">&#xE254;</i>
                </a>


                <a href="#deleteEmployeeModal" class="delete" data-toggle="modal">
                  <i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete">&#xE872;</i>
                </a>
              </td>

              <td>
                <?=$supp->CONS_AGENT?>
              </td>
              <td>
                <?=$supp->DISC1?>
              </td>
              <td>
                <?=$supp->DISC2?>
              </td>
              <td>
                <?=$supp->DISC3?>
              </td>
              <td>
                <?=$supp->DISC4?>
              </td>
              <td>
                <?=$supp->DISC5?>
              </td>
              <td>
                <?=  $supp->LAST_TRANS ?>
              </td>
              <td>
                <?=$supp->SUPP_CODE2?>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach;?>
            <?php else: ?>
            <tr>
              <?php for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++): ?>
              <td>
                <span class="text-danger"> Not Available </span>
              </td>
              <?php endfor; ?>
            </tr>
            <?php endif; ?>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

    </div>


    <!-- UPDATE MODAL -->


    <!--MODAL HERE-->
    <div class="modal fade" name="sfm_modal_edit " id="sfm_modal_edit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <!-- Modal Header -->
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
       <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
       <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
      </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
              Edit Supplier
            </h4>
          </div>
          <!-- Modal Body -->
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form id="form2" class="form-horizontal">
              <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                <!-- left column -->
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="new_name" class="col-sm-2 control-label bg-danger" style="visibility: hidden;">Supplier Code</label>
                    <span class="label label-default">Supplier Code</span>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="text" name="supp_codev1" id="supp_codev1" class="form-control" data-inputmask="'mask': '999999'">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="new_subname" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="visibility: hidden;">Address</label>
                    <span class="label label-default">Address</span>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="text" name="address1v1" class="form-control  col-md-10" id="address1v1" placeholder="">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="new_address" class="col-sm-2 control-label bg-danger" style="visibility: hidden;">Address 2</label>
                    <span class="label label-default">Address 2</span>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="text" name="address2v1" class="form-control  col-md-10" id="address2v1" placeholder="">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="new_addresssub" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="visibility: hidden;">Country</label>
                    <span class="label label-default">Country</span>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="text" name="countryv1" id="countryv1" class="form-control col-md-10" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- <div class="form-group"><label for="new_zip" class="col-sm-2 control-label bg-danger" style = "visibility: hidden;">Description</label><span class="label label-default" >Supplier Code</span><div class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="new_zip" placeholder=""></div><div class="col-sm-7"><label for="new_zip_detail" class="sr-only" style = "visibility: hidden;">City, State Country</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="new_zip_detail" placeholder="City, State Country" disabled=""></div></div> -->
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="new_addresssub" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="visibility: hidden;">Description</label>
                    <span class="label label-default">Description</span>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="text" name="descriptionv1" class="form-control" id="descriptionv1" placeholder="">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="new_phone" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="visibility: hidden;">Telephone Number</label>
                    <span class="label label-default">Telephone Number</span>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tel_numv1" id="tel_numv1" data-inputmask="'mask' : '(999) 999-9999'">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="new_phone" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="visibility: hidden;">Fax Number</label>
                    <span class="label label-default">Fax Number</span>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fax_numv1" id="fax_numv1" data-inputmask="'mask' : '(999) 999-9999'">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="new_name" class="col-sm-2 control-label bg-danger" style="visibility: hidden;">Consolidating Agent</label>
                    <span class="label label-default">Consolidating Agent</span>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="text" name="consol_agentv1" class="form-control" id="consol_agentv1" placeholder="">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>
                <!-- right column -->
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="new_subname" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="visibility: hidden;">Email</label>
                    <span class="label label-default">Email</span>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="emailv1" id="emailv1" placeholder="">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="new_name" class="col-sm-2 control-label bg-danger" style="visibility: hidden;">Contact Person</label>
                    <span class="label label-default">Contact Person</span>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contact_personv1" id="contact_personv1" placeholder="">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="new_subname" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="visibility: hidden;">Discount 1</label>
                    <span class="label label-default">Discount 1</span>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="disc1v1" id="disc1v1" placeholder="">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="new_address" class="col-sm-2 control-label bg-danger" style="visibility: hidden;">Discount 2</label>
                    <span class="label label-default">Discount 2</span>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="disc2v1" id="disc2v1" placeholder="">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="new_addresssub" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="visibility: hidden;">Discount 3</label>
                    <span class="label label-default">Discount 3</span>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="disc3v1" id="disc3v1" placeholder="">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="new_phone" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="visibility: hidden;">Discount 4</label>
                    <span class="label label-default">Discount 4</span>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="phone" class="form-control" name="disc4v1" id="disc4v1" placeholder="">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="new_phone" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="visibility: hidden;">Discount 5</label>
                    <span class="label label-default">Discount 5</span>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="phone" class="form-control" name="disc5v1" id="disc5v1" placeholder="">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="new_phone" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="visibility: hidden;">Last Transaction</label>
                    <span class="label label-default">Last Transaction</span>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_transactionv1" id="last_transactionv1" data-inputmask="'mask': '9999/99/99'">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="new_phone" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="visibility: hidden;">Old Supplier</label>
                    <span class="label label-default">Old Supplier</span>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="phone" class="form-control" name="old_supplierv1" id="old_supplierv1" placeholder="">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>

          </div>
          <!-- End main input boxes, starting a new "row" -->
          <!-- Modal Footer -->
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="newConsigneeReset">Reset</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
          </div>
          <!-- End Modal Footer -->
          </form>
        </div>
        <!-- End modal body div -->
      </div>
      <!-- End modal content div -->
    </div>
    <!-- End modal dialog div -->
  </div>
  <!-- End modal div -->

  <!-- /page content -->
```

### In the developers tools network tab/doc

[I found this when i enter a value in the modal and clicked add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vLc7.png)

Answer (score -1):

Use data- attribute to fetch the id of the row , store the id of the row in data-id attr and  before ajax request fetch that data-id from the edit button and run a query using that id.

```
    `<a href="example" data-id="$row_id" class="anything">Edit</a>`
```

And then in jquery , do it like

```
    var id = get_the_id_of_the_data-id_attribute;
```

And send it with that ajax request to ajax-page

Comment: I am doing that @Meiji